# Argument parsing and validation parsing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am new in C# programming. I want to run my Window Form Application through command line with one argument which is file name to be open in my Application. 
How can I do the following validation related to argument passed to Application:

1. Checking the argument string is valid file path (not a folder path)
2. If the argument string is Relative path (like "~\xyz.pdf") then it will generate and validate the absolute path (like "C:\Downloads\xyz.pdf").
3. If argument string is valid file path then file should be of specific extension (like file path is valid and it is PDF file only).

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You're new to programming? Take this advice: google around and read documentation and learn from code samples. I'm sure if you google your 3 individual points you will find adequate solutions for each of them.

Comment: Some hints [Path.GetFullPath][1], [Path.IsPathRooted][2].


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted

Answer (score 2):

1. `File.Exists` if you expect it to be an existing file, otherwise the only absolutely foolproof way is to attempt to create/open it.
2. If it's a standard relative path (xyz.pdf), you can use `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, path))`.  This will work if path is a relative or absolute path.
3. `Path.GetExtension`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you could try something like:

```
public static void Test(string path){
    // If there is no File at the desired location
    if (File.Exists(path) == false){
    }

    // Get the FullPath
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);

    // Check the Extension for .pdf
    if (path.EndsWith(".pdf")){

    }
    // Or you can do Path.GetExtension(path)
}
```